# Way to merge non-null columns of a SQL table based on an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario where I need to have all the non-null valued columns of a SQL table to be merged in a way that the output all all the fields populated with the last non-null value.

Input ->
[image]

Output ->[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by `ID` and select the `MAX` value of each column:

```sql
SELECT ID, MAX(ColA) AS ColA, MAX(ColB) AS ColB, MAX(ColC) AS ColC
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

**Edit:** For a bit column in SQL Server, you may cast to integer before taking the max:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CAST(ColA AS int)) AS ColA,
    MAX(CAST(ColB AS int)) AS ColB,
    MAX(CAST(ColC AS int)) AS ColC
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Is there another way than using MAX? MAX may not be applicable for few data types like BIT.

Comment: @Jim The above logic will work on nullable BIT as far as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got this comment while trying on my SQL Table 

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

Comment: @Jim Answer updated with a SQL Server option.